How to handle error creating threads in a loop
I'm into the Philosophers project, it is about handling threads and mutexes. For the project I need to create several threads, each thread runs a routine function and accesses shared resources. I discovered that when I test pthread_create() != 0 it causes a broad set of errors, from data race to segfault. When there is a thread error, I want to exit the loop, clean all resources and join created threads, but as they use mutexes I can not free locked values. I was thinking about using pthread_detach but not sure how to do it right.
#include "philo.h"

int create_threads(t_philo *data, t_program *set)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < data->num_of_philos)
    {
        if (pthread_create(&set->philos[i].thread,
                NULL, routine, &set->philos[i]))
        {
            ft_putstr_fd("Error thread create", 2);
            cleanup_all(set);
            return (0);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (1);
}

int join_threads(t_philo *data, t_program *set)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < data->num_of_philos)
    {
        if (pthread_join(set->philos[i].thread, NULL))
        {
            ft_putstr_fd("Error thread join", 2);
            cleanup_all(set);
            return (0);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (1);
}

void    cleanup_all(t_program *set)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < set->philos[0].num_of_philos)
    {
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&set->forks[i]);
        i++;
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&set->meal_lock);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&set->dead_lock);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&set->write_lock);
    free(set->forks);
    free(set->philos);
}

I tried to modify cleanup function but it is not working as expected. And limits of my project I cant use exit()

If you need debugging help, please provide a [mre].

One problem is that some of the resources you try to free (like the mutexes) might already be in use by the threads that was created successfully. You need to decide if it's okay for some of the threads to run, and for your program to continue, or if you should shut everything down and perhaps exit the program (or keep running, but do everything without threads, if that's possible). If you want to terminate, then you need to tell the successfully created threads to exit before cleaning up resources.

On a different note, when you report an error please remember to tell the user what the error was (or at least log it somewhere). Like for ptread_create which return an error code, not only a success/failure indicator.

And unless you try to create hundreds (or more) threads, if you have problems creating them the root cause might be something else, somewhere else in your program.

according to subject I create up to 200 threads. And I don't have any errors, just checked what happens if I enter into the if condition when phtread_create != 0
if (pthread_join( i == 3 || set->philos[i].thread, NULL))

If you are not going to have the threads cooperatively terminate but rather are going to yank resources away from them, then you cannot join the threads. You may be looking for pthread_cancel.

It sounds like you are trying to code to recover from coding bugs by resetting to a known state but not exiting. This is not possible. There are always bugs that your cleanup will not be able to handle. You should test and debug your code so that it works properly. That said, you might look at pthread_mutexattr_setrobust which tells mutexes to release if the holding thread dies (e.g. calls pthread_exit()). And  pthread_cancel might help you.

The best alternative in the event of an error from pthread_create() is sometimes simply to terminate the program with exit() or abort().  Preferably after printing a diagnostic that describes the nature of the error, which you can get by setting errno to the pthread_create() return value, then immediately calling perror().
